# Convert Lists to DataFrame using Logic based on List Name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

I'm trying to build a dataframe from the following lists:

```
A = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3', 'item 4', 'item 5']

B = ['item 2','item 4']

C = ['item 1', 'item 5']
```

I want the list name (or some representation of that name) to be the corresponding value, as such:

```
dA = [{'item':x, 'A':True} for x in A]
dB = [{'item':x, 'B':True} for x in B]
dC = [{'item':x, 'C':True} for x in C]
```

Currently, I'm building my dataframe using some ugly methods. I'd love a best practices solution here:

```
dfA = pd.DataFrame.from_records(dA)
dfB = pd.DataFrame.from_records(dB)
dfC = pd.DataFrame.from_records(dC)

df = pd.merge(dfA,dfB, 'outer').merge(dfC,'outer').fillna(False)

# Result:
    item    A   B   C
0   item 1  True    False   True
1   item 2  True    True    False
2   item 3  True    False   False
3   item 4  True    True    False
4   item 5  True    False   True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do this without merge

```
import pandas as pd

# list all unique items (in case there are not all present in A)
all_items = list(set(A+ B+C))
# create a dataframe with only item column
df = pd.DataFrame({'item':all_items})
# add boolean columns
df['A'] = df['item'].isin(A)
df['B'] = df['item'].isin(B)
df['C'] = df['item'].isin(C)

#   item    A   B   C
#0  item 4  True    True    False
#1  item 3  True    False   False
#2  item 2  True    True    False
#3  item 1  True    False   True
#4  item 5  True    False   True
```

If you wanted something prettier or you have more columns to create, you could also use a dictionary

```
dict_list = {'A': A, 'B': B, 'C':C}
for col in dict_list.keys():
  df[col] = df['item'].isin(dict_list[col])
```

Comment: Clever. I didn't realize you could add sets like that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [pandas.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
import pandas as pd

A = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3', 'item 4', 'item 5']
B = ['item 2', 'item 4']
C = ['item 1', 'item 5']

# generate series
s = pd.Series({'A': A, 'B': B, 'C': C})

# apply get dummies and transform
result = pd.get_dummies(s.apply(pd.Series).stack()).sum(level=0).T

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
        A  B  C
item 1  1  0  1
item 2  1  1  0
item 3  1  0  0
item 4  1  1  0
item 5  1  0  1
```

If you must have boolean values you could do, instead:

```
result = pd.get_dummies(s.apply(pd.Series).stack()).sum(level=0).T.astype(bool)
```

Comment: Really clever approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try `pd.crosstab`

```
arr = np.concatenate([A, B, C])
col_arr = np.repeat(['A', 'B', 'C'], [len(A), len(B), len(C)])
pd.crosstab(index=arr, columns=col_arr)

Out[106]:
col_0   A  B  C
row_0
item 1  1  0  1
item 2  1  1  0
item 3  1  0  0
item 4  1  1  0
item 5  1  0  1
```

---

If you want `True/False`, just chain an additional `eq(1)`

```
pd.crosstab(index=arr, columns=col_arr).eq(1)

Out[108]:
col_0      A      B      C
row_0
item 1  True  False   True
item 2  True   True  False
item 3  True  False  False
item 4  True   True  False
item 5  True  False   True
```

Comment: What does `crosstab` do?

Comment: @YaakovBressler: crosstab builds cross tabulation table showing the frequency of certain groups of data. Crosstab accepts `array-like, Series, or list of arrays/Series`. Your data are lists, so crosstab has advantage that it works directly on those lists without constructing pandas dataframe or series. For more info, you may read ít docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html

Comment: Very helpful. I'll look into that.